# Building a auto-refreshing, nested List in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

how can i achieve to dynamically generate and update a nested list in EmberJS?

My Model looks something like:

```
App.Node = Em.Object.extend({
    id: 0,
    parentId: 0,
    title: ""
});
```

The `parentId` represents the `id` of the direct parent element.

If i have data (instances of the model lying in the content of the controller) like:

```
[{
    id:1,
    title:"Parent Element"
}, {
    id:2,
    parentId:1,
    title:"Child Element"
}]
```

I want to get a list like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Parent Element</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Child Element</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

This is what i got: http://jsfiddle.net/LhTCm/ (not runnable, but its easy to understand).

As i mentioned before, i want to build a nested list, which ui updates automatically as soon as the model-data changes.

Hope you can help!

Comment: I've updated your JSFiddle so it is functional. http://jsfiddle.net/tbartelmess/HMhe3/

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing you'll need is a better object model. Storing the parentID on your object doesn't help a lot. You need actual references to your objects, best in both directions, if you just want to display it, just storing the children will be fine as well. Your model should look like this:

```
App.Node = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    parent: null,
    title: "",
    children: []

});
```

Then when you load in your data, you'll have to make sure that you map them correctly.

Your actual template would look like this

```
<ul>
  {{#each node}}
    <li>{{title}}
        {{#each children}}
             <ul><li>{{title}}</li></ul>
        {{/each}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**You also might want to look at ember-data if your model is getting more complex (https://github.com/emberjs/data)**

Comment: But then i can only nest 1 Item deep, right? I should have mentioned, that i want nearly endless nesting :)

Comment: if you want endless nesting, you won't be able to do it entirely in the template layer. What you'd have to do is to make a view that is rendering one layer and add subviews of itself for the next layers.