# How can I build a recursive view in Ember?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

In my application I have an item called *block* which can contain and be contained by other *block* items. To keep things simple, lets say these blocks can be infinitely nested.

I want to know if I can create recursive views corresponding to the blocks that are also nested. Each view will be rendered as a `DIV` containing its children and residing inside its parent `DIV`?

While the views are similar in terms of what they can contain, their actual content that will be obtained from the server can be different. Here is an example data:

```
App.blocks.set('content',[
    Em.Object.create({title:"One", id:"1", is_inside:"0"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"Two", id:"2", is_inside:"1"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"Three", id:"3", is_inside:"0"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"Four", id:"4", is_inside:"3"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"Five", id:"5", is_inside:"4"})
])
```

In this example, block one would be rendered as root (assume 0 is root which means not inside any other block). Block two would be rendered inside block one and so on.

I noticed a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857781/building-a-auto-refreshing-nested-list-in-emberjs) has been asked a while ago, but I am not satisfied with the answer there. I feel there must be an elegant way to achieve this in Ember.

Can you point me to an example of how this can be done in Ember? If not, any advice that could help me make progress and refine my question would also be very appreciated.

Edit: Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/nyfk8/4/) that I made with some initial data that we could use as starting point. With your help hopefully I can make those `DIVs` nested based on their *is_inside* relation. I have updated the post to use this simpler example.

Comment: Do you mind also adding what you've got so far? Your model object, view and handlebars templates would be great.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Bradley. I have edited question with a simpler example and a jsFiddle we could use as starting point. Note that its not nested yet, hopefully you can help me make it nested :)

Answer (score 0):

Take this as a **hint**, I think the `layout` property of `Ember.View`comes in rescue...It works this way

```
App.myView =  Ember.View.extend({
  layoutName: "parent",
  templateName: "child"
})

<script type="text/handlebars" data-template-name="parent">
  Who's your Daddy ??<br> {{yield}} <br> ######
</script>


<script type="text/handlebars" data-template-name="child">
  I'm your son !
</script>
```

Will result in the following html

```
<div id="ember1" class="ember-view">
  Who's your Daddy?
  <div id="ember-2" class="ember-view">
    I'm your son !
  </div>
  ######
</div>
```

Model your data first, then use `for` or `while` loops in js to create views, I don't think using handlebar helpers for recursion is a good idea.

**Edited Section**
There can be a better way than this...but check this out, and here you are not limiting the nesting to one level, right ?

```
App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "main"
})

App.View1 = Ember.View.extend({
  id: 1,
  templateName: "view1",
  parentId: "main"
})


App.View2 = Ember.View.extend({
  id: 2,
  templateName: "view2",
  parentId: 1
})


App.View3 = Ember.View.extend({
  id: 3,
  templateName: "view3",
  parentId: 1
})


App.View4 = Ember.View.extend({
  id: 4,
  templateName: "view4",
  parentId: 3
})

App.View5 = Ember.View.extend({
  id: 5,
  templateName: "view5",
  parentId: "main"
})

App.viewArray = [App.View1, App.View2, App.View3, App.View4, App.View5];

App.viewArray.forEach(view, function(){
  parentView = App.viewArray.findProperty("id", view.get('parentId'))
  view.set("layoutName", parentView.get('templateName'))
})
```

Comment: +1 for the effort and helpful hints. But doesn’t your suggested method here assume that the parent/child relation exist only one level deep? In my case I don’t know many level deep the data would be nested. Do you think I can achieve that following your *hint*? If yes, can you provide a hint how the *recursive* representation can be captured here? Thanks again!

Comment: @Unespecified: something like this is what I had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/uHYYz/3/

Comment: Ya I understood your question, see the edited section of the answer

Comment: notice that I said **blocks can be infinitely nested** by that I mean I dont know how many views I will need and how many levels they are nested. I simply need to create the views dynamically. A static representation like what you provided is not going to work in this case

Comment: This was kind of logic...Whenever or from wherever you get the views during run-time, keep pushing them to an array & the array must have an observer which does the above defined logic so that whenever a new view is added it gets nested inside it's parent, and of-course upto any level